# App "Unable to be Downloaded at this time"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, installation

I have tried sending a .ipa file through appbox and almost all devices I send it to say "Unable to download this app at this time." I have tried changing my build number, re-doing my certificates, changing platform settings, etc. Nothing I am finding has worked. I paid for the apple developer program, exported the file Ad Hoc. None of the devices I have tested it on have allowed for device management/ profiles in the general settings. Also, every related question is generally from 2013 or later.

I have searched countless forums attempted countless suggested solutions and nothing is working. I can get it to work on 1 device and that's the one I had plugged into the mac at one point. I have since uninstalled and reinstalled the app and it still works over the wireless installation process.
Does anyone have any other solutions to this? I feel like I've exhausted google search.

I am pulling my build from Unity if that makes any difference. Yes, I have device SDK selected in the player settings in Unity.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: have you added device ID to your developer account, and then created Ad-Hoc provision profile?

Comment: Are all the devices on which you are trying to install the app, is added in the developer account?

Comment: @PiyushRathi, yes I added that in.

Comment: @Bmacin I am unable to locate the developer tools on the devices I have tested it on.

Comment: As you comment ' I wanted anyone with a compatible device to be able to download and install' you need to create In-House profiles from an enterprise account, which is independent of device IDs

Comment: Hold the phone, so if I want my app to be accessible to the public for download, I have to have an enterprise account? Even though I am already enrolled in the apple developer program?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add UDID of all device which u wants to download.
2. Use https://www.diawi.com/ for sending ipa file ok.
3. Or go for testflight that is very useful for testing.

Comment: It's a demo of the app. I wanted anyone with a compatible device to be able to download and install the game. There is no way I can do this using test flight. Also, Diawi.com's links only last for 24 hours. using AppBox allows the links to be used from my dropbox which is more convenient for everyone. Or so I have found thus far.

Comment: then you have to Add there UDID there is no option for you

Comment: I got your problem now, to distribute the app to anyone with compatible device. You need to have an Enterprise developer account and create a profile for Adhoc and App store distribution. In case of individual dev account, you need to specify the device id's for adhoc distribution and can add upto 100 devices.

Comment: yes if still issues are there, then raise an issue on that AppBox @vineet will message you

Comment: Wow, I am blown away by how ridiculous that is. It's really hard to believe that Apple would require you to jump through so many hoops and pay so much money just to develop apps for their platform. This has me really rethinking my strategy. Anyway, thanks for your swift response. It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Think, who is going for Apple products and store they are not kinda peoples. For App, store maintenance and its apps are far better than other platforms so it should keep their dignity and if you want to use you have to go through that there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Since the apparent solution was posted in the comments and not as an answer I will put it here. With credit going to @Bmacin and @Ashutos Sahoo.

You cannot simply link people to a download of your game. Unless you are an "Apple Enterprise Developer" (Which currently cost $299 USD btw). At that point, they give you the ability to create in-house profiles and you can then get your app into devices.
Well, theoretically- I have not tried this because I already spent enough money enrolling in the apple developer program.

I hope this saves at least one person sometime when they are looking for a solution.

Comment: The enterprise development program isn't appropriate here either. It is for distribution of apps to employees of an organisation, not the general public. Once your app is ready for release, you do so via the App Store. If it is in a test state then you can use TestFlight to invite specific testers. Apple does not allow general distribution of apps that have not been through app review